# Vim (Windows) - new help files do not work

Tags: plugins, text-editor, installation, vim

I have downloaded several new plugins which come with a help file.  None of them seem to work from within Vim.

I have the Windows version of gVim and the install dir contains a folder called:

vimfiles
vim72

Both folder contain a plugin and doc folder.  Where am I supposed to put the plugin?

So when I use :help [helpfile], it says it cannot find it, but I can see it in the doc folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should extract the new plugins in `vimfiles`, so then your new helpfiles goes to `vimfiles\doc`, then issue a

```
:helptags C:\where\you\had\installed\vim\vimfiles\doc
```

And then you can use your great new helpfiles.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

If your installation directory is `c:\vim`, run this command:

```
:helptags c:\vim\vimfiles\doc
```

That will update the tags file in the documentation directory and the help should start working.